# Python Loop writing to CSV files

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a csv file for each query output. I have multiple select queries (queries.sql) in a single SQL file and i am looping through it to execute in database and write each query output to its own csv file. When i execute the code all queries are executing in the database but only the last query result set is being written to csv file, rest all csv files are with no records. Any help is appreciated.

```
  col_pattern = "(^|[_-])SSN#?($|[_-])|^SS#?$|(^|[_-])(SSN|SOC.*SEC.*).?(ID|NO|NUMBERS?|NUM|NBR|#)($|[_-])|^SOCIAL.?SEC(URITY)?#?$"
SQL = "select OWNER||'_'||TABLE_NAME||'_'||column_name from ALL_TAB_COLS where REGEXP_LIKE (column_name, :1) and owner NOT IN ('SYS','SYSMAN') order by table_name,column_name"
cursor.execute(SQL,(col_pattern,))
for row_data in cursor:
    if not row_data[0].startswith('BIN$'):
        fileName = row_data[0]
        csv_file_dest = "/u01/exp/test/identity/csvdata/"+ fileName + ".csv"
        outputFile = open(csv_file_dest,'w') # 'wb'
        output = csv.writer(outputFile, dialect='excel')

f = open('/u01/exp/test/identity/queries.sql')
full_sql = f.read()
sql_commands = full_sql.replace('\n', "").split(';')[:-1]
#print(sql_commands)
for sql_command in sql_commands:
    curs2 = cursor.execute(sql_command)
    if printHeader: # add column headers if requested
        cols = []
        for col in curs2.description:
            cols.append(col[0])
        output.writerow(cols)
    for row_data in curs2: # add table rows
        output.writerow(row_data)
    outputFile.close()
```

Comment: It seems like you are writing to the same file each time in the second part. Which is the last file from the first part. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: You should consider to use pandas. There is a command pandas.read_sql and then with .to_csv you save to file.

Comment: Thank you @mkrieger1 and rpanai,  I will change the code to get the output variable populated dynamically inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is because all the SQL data is being written to whatever the last thing is that the variable "output" was set to. So the file that the variable "output" is set to is just being constantly overwritten.

Comment: Thank you very much. After i read your comments i noticed that output variable is not dynamically changing according to the need i wanted. I will have to modify the code somehow to get the value for output variable populated inside the loop.